# Electron cannot read property 'path' of undefined videos I have uploaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to convert a video that I have successfully loaded up to an Electron with React project. I did not have a problem adding the videos, but when I try to convert the video to a different file type I get the error below:

> Uncaught Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of
>   undefined
>       at EventEmitter.ipcMain.on (/Users/danale/Projects/ElectronCode/boilerplates/convert/index.js:37:32)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at WebContents. (/Users/danale/Projects/ElectronCode/boilerplates/convert/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/api/web-contents.js:247:37)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at WebContents.emit (events.js:191:7)

Its referencing this code below:

```
ipcMain.on("conversion:start", (event, videos) => {
  const video = videos[0];

  const outputDirectory = video.path.split(video.name)[0];
  const outputName = video.name.split(".")[0];
  const outputPath = `${outputDirectory}${outputName}.${video.format}`;
  console.log(outputPath);
  // ffmpeg(video.path).output();
});
```

but I do not see anything wrong with the code. Why is `videos` undefined now? I have been able to add them successfully.

Here is my action creator:

```
export const convertVideos = videos => (dispatch, getState) => {
  ipcRenderer.send("conversion:start", videos);
};
```

This is my reducer:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case VIDEO_COMPLETE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.path]: { ...action.payload, complete: true } };
    case VIDEO_PROGRESS:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.path]: action.payload };
    case ADD_VIDEOS:
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, 'path')}
    case ADD_VIDEO:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.path]: action.payload };
    case REMOVE_VIDEO:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload.path);
    case REMOVE_ALL_VIDEOS:
      return INITIAL_STATE
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

`convertVideos` is being called from `src/components/ConvertPanel.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import * as actions from '../actions';

class ConvertPanel extends Component {

  onCancelPressed = () => {
    this.props.removeAllVideos();
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="convert-panel">
        <button className="btn red" onClick={this.onCancelPressed}>
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button className="btn" onClick={this.props.convertVideos}>
          Convert!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(null, actions)(ConvertPanel)
);
```

Comment: could you show us where `convertVideos` is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when DanStarns asked for me to show where `convertVideos` is being called and I posted the `ConvertPanel.js` file, I felt something was amiss there, this did not seem right:

```
export default withRouter(
  connect(null, actions)(ConvertPanel)
);
```

No need for a `mapStateToProps` there? The `videos` object was defined when adding videos but it was not being set right by the Redux back-end when it came time to convert the file type of said object.

So for the convert button I decided to use an arrow function and then passed `convertVideos` the `videos` prop. That in itself was not enough and I believed I also needed a `mapStateToProps` and after lots of painful wrangling, this is what I came up with that worked:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="convert-panel">
        <button className="btn red" onClick={this.onCancelPressed}>
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => this.props.convertVideos(this.props.videos)}
        >
          Convert!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { videos: _.at(state.videos, _.keys(state.videos)) };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    actions
  )(ConvertPanel)
);
```

For the above to work I had to import `lodash` library and I do not like the way that `mapStateToProps` looks, if anyone has a more elegant version, I would be willing to adopt it.